# Does the order of gems in your Gemfile make a difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

Is the order in which you list your gems important? Are these two blocks equivalent?

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
```

And

```
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
```

Comment: Well, it's but long winded for a comment, but CarrierWave is not writing the image url to the model correctly. I'm going to delete everything and start again. If that doesn't work, I'll come with more info.

Comment: Are you using `fog` storage?  File storage isn't supposed to store the url, but the file name.  The url is generated based on the config.

Comment: I was using `fog`. In fact, that's when everything broke. But `object.image => nil` anyway, so nothing was being saved.

Answer (score 15):

When you use `Bundle.require` (which Rails does), Gems are required in the order they appear in the Gemfile. In wasn’t always like this, but [has been this way for a while](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/f17183b53edc96162cd2e20255d6bc315779b5cf).

Since Carrierwave requires RMagick explicitly when it is needed, I don’t think it should matter in your case; but strictly speaking the two blocks are not equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

<s>Bundler doesn't load gem dependencies by the order that you list them</s>*, but it does go by source priority using this criteria:

1. Explicit path or git options append to a gem dependency, e.g.:

   ```
   gem 'some-gem', github: 'somebody/some-gem'
   ```
2. Explicitly defined dependencies for gems that are otherwise required implicitly from other gem dependecies, i.e., `gem 'actionmailer'` gem is implicitly required by `gem 'rails'`
3. If you have multiple sources added it will search from last to first.

See https://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY

---

- 

**Edit:** As per Matt's answer, depending on what you're trying to do (or what gems you're loading) the order **MIGHT** matter. See [Even with bundler your gem order can be significant](https://makandracards.com/makandra/775-even-with-bundler-your-gem-order-can-be-significant).

Comment: You're talking about the order of the sources checked for a gem, but I believe the question was about whether the order of the gem statements in a Gemfile matters -- and I believe the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Hello from 2022 using Bundler 2.3.11:

Ordering in the Gemfile does not matter as far as I know. The docs for Bundler do not appear to say this definitively, but see below.

##### Real life example:

Recently we installed Sidekiq Enterprise, and the `sidekiq-ent` gem has a dependency on `sidekiq-pro` and both have a dependency on `sidekiq`.

from our `Gemfile.lock`:

```rb
  specs:
    sidekiq-ent (2.5.0)
      einhorn (>= 0.7.4)
      sidekiq (>= 6.5.0)
      sidekiq-pro (>= 5.5.0)
    sidekiq-pro (5.5.0)
      sidekiq (>= 6.5.0)
```

Rubocop was yelling at us for using `sidekiq-pro` before `sidekiq-ent`:

```
Bundler/OrderedGems: Gems should be sorted in an alphabetical order within their section of the Gemfile. Gem sidekiq-ent should appear before sidekiq-pro.
```

So we tried it Rubocop's way, and no issues ¯_(ツ)_/¯